# Querying on Managed Metadata for term and parent terms

Tags: 2013, search

I have a Managed Metadata field called Geography using the following term set as an example.

> - North America
>
>   - Canada
>
>     - Toronto
>   - United States
>
>     - New York

This Geography managed metadata field gets mapped to a managed property called owstaxidGeography when a full crawl is performed.

What I would like to do is issue a query so that when owstaxidGeography is compared to Toronto, it would return all content tagged with Toronto, Canada, or North America (i.e. the term and its parents)

When building search keyword queries there is a syntax to match on the

a) Exact Term

> #0 in the query string before the term ID means query for only the specified term ID. (e.g. owstaxidGeography:#052263385-1fc3-4323-8d6b-50c8f6c3c45d)

b) Term and its Children

> # before the term ID means query for the specified term ID or the ID of any of that term’s child terms.  (e.g. owstaxidGeography:#52263385-1fc3-4323-8d6b-50c8f6c3c45d)

Is there a syntax to match on the term and its parents?

Comment: Just got the same, found this post..! http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2014/03/s15e01-kql-basics.html Hope it helps, it helped me